# want to show a link only for a user who is logged in for all else it show either be hidden or disabled in angularjs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a form

and i want that in "mark your attendence here "link should be visible only to the user which is logged in (/or disabled for the not logged in users .).please tell me how to do this :
here is my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in user.users">
    <td>{{ person._id }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.joiningDate }}</td>
    <td ng-show="user.loggedIn"><a href="/users/{{ person._id }}/attendence" >Mark your attendence here</a></td>
    <td class="col-sm-2">
        <a ng-href="/users/{{ person._id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="user.deleteUser(person._id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

if i use user.loggedIn service then because of a particular user logged in it show the attendence column

Comment: do have you have bool value like person.loggedIn =true of false??? or user.loggedIn=true or false?

Comment: no..i have made a service authservice in which i have made a function called loggedIn() .which i am calling in my html page

Comment: ok.Once you call a function what happens? which $scope you are working with in success callback functiion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in controller. Call the authservice from that function and on authentication success , set a Boolean to true. Give that boolean in ngShow.